# Return to calling activity if running, otherwise start a new one?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity which performs OAuth authorization, token renewal etc.

I call it from several places. When it completes, it usually launches my "default" activity (a list of items owned by the user), but in some cases (e.g. when editing an item) I'd like for it to return to the calling activity instead.

So, I'd like to check if the calling activity is running. If it is, I'd like to return to the calling activity. Otherwise I'd like to launch a new one (which I can already do).

TL;DR: How can I check if the calling activity is still running?

Comment: if you did not `finish()` the calling activity, then when the called activities finish, they will return to that activity.

Comment: Yeah. But if I did `finish()`, it will end my application if I don't launch a new one.

Comment: yes, that is my idea, don't finish the caller activity, and finish the oAuth activity, this way it will do it's job and close, that will show the activity below which is the caller activity (that you did not finish)

Comment: I understood that. But in most cases I WANT to finish the earlier activity, because I don't have any intention of returning to it - I want to launch a new one instead. What I want to do is find out if I have `finish()`ed the caller or not.

Comment: ok now i got it :) i thought you want the other thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own implementation of [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) to manage all activities. Just create your implementation of interface:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new CustomActivityLifecycleCallback());
    }
}
```